# Xcode 9.3 - NSPredicate Bool crash

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9.3

After the Xcode 9.3 update, I've noticed that if you want to have Predicate like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "preferred = %@", true as CVarArg)
```

You have a crash. But in Xcode 9.2 this wasn't a problem. Any idea?

Comment: It seems it's not about Xcode, but it's about Swift update (Xcode 9.3 includes Swift 4.1)

Answer (score 8):

// Solution 3 [ [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) ]

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "preferred == TRUE")
```

---

The exception occurs because `true` is not an object (`%@`). You need the `%d` placeholder

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "preferred = %d", true)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of investigation, I've discovered how to fix this. In short:

```
// Solution 1 [ NSNumber ]
let bool = NSNumber(booleanLiteral: true)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "preferred = %@", bool as CVarArg)

// Solution 2 [ Bool ] (static example)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "preferred == YES")
```

As also explained [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7411), it's simply better to deal with Obj-C type instead of Swift type when we have to deal with this kind of methods.

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "preferred = %@", true as NSNumber)` is another option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can also use this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "preferred = true")
```

Comment: Yep, it's also a solution! I also noticed that. Basically it's just better to avoid to pass swift boolean as CVarArg like I did at first. Can't understand exactly why, but nevermind.