# Fetch request not working in Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, core-data, swift4, swift4.1

I have a predicate that is a Bool set to false (mostly).  It stopped working correctly in Swift 4.1 when I upgraded yesterday.

The predicate is:

```
requestData.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "delete == %@", false as CVarArg);
```

How do I check if this value is false in the Core Data store? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placeholder `%@` is for objects, the placeholder for a `Bool` is `%d`

However there is a simpler syntax if the argument is a constant

```
requestData.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "delete == FALSE")
```

Comment: Yes and I can also use NSNumber with value too. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50389458/1187415.

Answer (score 0):

You should get your predicate working by using:

```
requestData.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "delete == NO")
```

Unfortunately I can't tell you why your example with `CVarArg` did stop working - but since it is not needed in your example I would try using the other initializer with the optional `argumentArray` parameter: `init(format:argumentArray:)`

---

[The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html) in section *Boolean Values* says:

> You specify and test for equality of Boolean values as illustrated in the following examples:

```
NSPredicate *newPredicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:aBool]];
NSPredicate *testForTrue =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"anAttribute == YES"];
```